# ReactJS - Babel usage problems to compile .jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

For a quick test, i've created my `main.jsx` file written in `ES6` for my `ReacJS` app:

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'

class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div className="test">...</div>;
    }

}
```

Then i compile my code with `browserify` and `babel`:

```
browserify -t babel main.jsx -o public/js/bundle.js
```

I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'babel'`

What's the cleanest way to compile `ES6` code with `ReactJS`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Browserify, you can use the transform 'babelify' to compile your ES6 code.  Check it out here:

https://github.com/babel/babelify

Comment: I've installed babelify, i've launched `browserify main.jsx -o public/js/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]` but i get this error: `Couldn't find preset "es2015" while parsing file`

Comment: npm install babel-preset-es2015

Comment: Ok, babel-preset-es2015  and babel-preset-react was missing, thank you all